How to plot multiple data sets imported from excel worksheet in matplotlib?
I need help with plotting the data from excel into matplotlib. The data is taken from one worksheet. The columns have similar structure:column a -x values, column b - y values, column c - x values, d - y values etc.. I want python to loop through the data set and plot it in separate plots. Also I want to learn how to combine multiple data sets in one plot. I would like to add reference name as a title to each graph. Here is what I managed so far:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl as xl
df=pd.read_excel("C:\\temp\\test.xlsx", 'Sheet1', skipwors=5)
x=df['distance']
y=df['HV']
plt.xlim(0.1,20)
plt.ylim(100,1000)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show

Excel file looks like this:

It does what I want with one x and one y columns. However, I want to add multiple columns next to each other in the same worksheet and create a loop to plot them. Thank you in advance for any tips!
I tried to plot one data set and it worked. I dont know how to create a loop.

Does this answer your question? How to plot multiple dataframes in subplots

You must iterate with groups on the columns of the df. This should do the trick.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl as xl
df=pd.read_excel("/content/test.xlsx")
print(df.columns)

def grouped(iterable, n):
    return zip(*[iter(iterable)]*n)

pair_count = len(list(grouped(df.columns,2)))
pair = 1
plt.figure(figsize=(10,2))
for x_col,y_col in grouped(df.columns,2):
  x=np.array(df[x_col].values)
  y=np.array(df[y_col].values)
  plt.subplot(1,pair_count,pair)
  plt.plot(x,y)
  plt.title(f"{pair}. th plot")
  plt.xlabel(f"Column {x_col} values")
  plt.ylabel(f"Column {y_col} values")
  pair += 1

plt.show()

The result:

Content of the test.xlsx:


Thank you so much Mustafa! It works perfectly! Just some fine tuning: is there a way to put in a line plt.title(f"{pair}.th plot") the actual name of a data set, which is placed above the row headings for x, y: column 1/row 1 reference column b/row 1 reference_name. Each x and y data set are built in the same way.

I am sorry, I couldn't understand the exact structure of the file. If you can provide a small part of the file, I think I can help. Maybe you can edit the question and an image.

I added the example of excel file. Thanks a lot for your help!

For example do you want to make the title for the first plot "distance-HV dataset"? If so, you can change plt.title(f"{pair}. th plot") line to plt.title(f"{x_col}-{y_col} dataset")

almost but I want the title of each graph be a specific name which in my excel table example is shown as place holder 'Name'. I need to be able to identify the data sets by name in the title. When I read the excel file I skip the first 5 lines where some additional info. But I need to read one line above 'distance'|'HV' row. I dont know if it is possible first to skip those rows and then extract one row as a title for the graph.
